# Displaying Data from Database Using PDO, Table is empty

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to display MySQL database information into HTML. I've researched 20+ topics in this forum on the subject, trying to use their solutions, yet I am still having issues. The following code is being executed. I'm trying to read the courseNumber, section, instructor, startTime, endTime, days, and name from a database. I thought that the foreach would display all of my data from the query, but there is nothing being displayed, only my table headers and user input button at the bottom. I have made sure that the database is populated. I've attempted to use a while loops and different foreach loops from online solutions, but haven't had any luck. If it isn't obvious, I'm a programming student and am trying to get a grasp on the subject. All time and effort is greatly appreciated!

```
//this is the function I'm using to call my database. This part is working correctly(executed below) 
static function readAll()
    {
        $pdo = Database::connect();
        $sql = "Select * from course";
        $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $data->execute();
        $data->fetchAll();
        Database::disconnect();
        return $data;
    }


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
label{display:inline-block;width:100px;margin-bottom:10px;}
</style>


<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row">
<div class="col">
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Course Number</th>
<th>Section</th>
<th>Instructor</th>
<th>Start Time</th>
<th>End Time</th>
<th>Days</th>
<th>Name</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
include_once "courseController.php";
include_once "schedule.php";
include_once "student.php";


$courses = courseController::readAll();

foreach($courses as $courseDB) {
echo '<tr>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['courseNumber'] . '</td>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['section'] . '</td>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['startTime'] . '</td>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['endTime'] . '</td>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['instructor'] . '</td>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['days'] . '</td>' .
'<td>' . $courseDB['name'] . '</td>' .
'</tr>';
}

?>

</tbody>
</table>

</div>
</div>

<div class="row">
<form = method ="post" action = "process.php">
<div class = "col">
<div class="form-group">
<select class="form-control" name="ActionType">
<option id="create" value="create">Create!</option>
<option id="update" value="update">Update..</option>
<option id="delete" value="delete">Delete :(</option>

</select>
</div>
</div>

<div class = "col">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</div>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$data->fetchAll();` returns the results, so you actually need to store the data somewhere. Try: `$result = $data->fetchAll();` and then return that value instead `return $result`; http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Everything is working as it should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return result received  from `$data->execute();`. change your `readAll()` as below

```
static function readAll()
{
    $records = array();
    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $sql = "Select * from course";
    $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $data->execute();
    $records = $data->fetchAll();
    Database::disconnect();
    return $records;
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much, everything is working perfectly.

Comment: @ZachLatture If this solution works for you, you should accept it to let people know that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

you  should use this

```
    $data=  $pdo->query($sql);
  $result = $query->rowCount();
  if($result > 0){
$r =    $result->fetchAll();
  }else{
   $r = 0;
}
return $r;
```